# PSQL - password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: password, 14.10, postgresql

I have freshly installed postgresql 9.4 on my ubuntu 14.10 box and I have run `\password` as the `postgres` user and given it the password `postgres`:

```
$> sudo -u postgres psql
=# \password
Enter new password: postgres
Enter it again: postgres
=# \q
$>
```

I have also updated the `/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf` with `listen_addresses='localhost'` and restarted postgresql.

**ISSUE**

When I run `psql -U postgres -h localhost` I am still prompted for a password.

**QUESTION**

What else should I try in order to prevent being prompted for a password while executing `psql` commands locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005952/can-connect-to-postgres-through-localhost-without-password-but-not-through-127-0). The issue was that I was missing the `~/.pgpass` file. So I created one with access permission `600` (this is important) and added the following lines:

```
localhost:*:*:postgres:postgres
127.0.0.1:*:*:postgres:postgres
```

After a restart of `postgresql` all was well :)

Comment: Thanks! Helped me on postgresql 11, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This is what I've been looking for

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer and it works fine for me.

**Change postgres user’s password**

PostgreSQL is provided with a default user named ‘postgres’. For this, we will use this role and change its password. Run following command to jump into postgreSQL cmd.

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

Enter your root/sudo password. This will take you to the psql cmd which will be prompted like

```
postgres=#
```

Here ‘postgres’ is the username you’re currently logged in with. Now run following command to change password.

```
\password postgres
```

This will prompt you to enter your new password for user ‘postgres’ and then will ask you to confirm it by reentering it. You’re done with possible solution.